# Use ApplicationInsights to track telemetry from a FunctionApp generates a lot of logs

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I'm using a `FunctionApp` that sends telemetries of type `Trace`, `Event` and `Exception` to **Application Insights**. I've noticed that most of the logs are generated by the FunctionAPP sdk itself.

Is there a way to limit these kind of logs and left only the logs tracked via the TrackTrace, TrackException and TrackEvent method call?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64151440/932728)

Comment: Just like @PeterBons' answer, upgrade the log level, and make your trace, exception and event to a higher grade.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Peter Bons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932728/peter-bons) and [tiny-wa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14574199/tiny-wa) posting your comment section discussion as answer which would be helpful for other community members

You can use the Log Levels and Categories when you write traces from your application code.
Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-monitoring?tabs=cmd#log-levels-and-categories

Assigning logged items to a category, will have control over telemetry generated from specific sources in function app. Categories make it easier to run analytics over collected data. Traces written from function code are assigned to individual categories based on the function name.
Learn more about [configuring Categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-categories)

More discussion on similar issue can be referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64151055/application-insight-logging-only-log-what-i-say-and-nothing-else/64151440#64151440)